# Native Instruments FM8 - Voicing / Unisono

Tags: synthesizer

I recently starting using Native Instruments FM8.

Up till now I have been using Native Instruments Massive and I know that there is a Voicing Tab in there where you can change the Unisono and other Voicing properties.

I was wondering if FM8 has something similar? and if so where I could find it and if it differs to the way Voicing works in Massive.

Any help or tips are appreciated. Thank You in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep!  In the master tab on the navigator.  You'll find some other cool options there as well like glide and analog/digital modeling.